# Javascript Statement for Keywords in Description Tags

Tags: javascript

Trying to extract any weather-related keywords from an og:description tag to make sure these related articles are not scrapped into a recommendation collector. Getting stuck on the return keywords; statement after my JS. It doesn't really matter if it returns a list of other keywords since these don't include weather related information anyway. Here's what I've got:

```
var keywords = $('meta[property="og:description"]').attr("content").split(',')
var excludes = ["storm", "storms", "tornado", "snow", "rain", "heat", "cold", "blizzard", "hurricane", "flood", "heat-wave"] 
return keywords;
```

I also tried something like this unsuccessfully:

```
var elementContent = document.querySelector('meta[property="og:description"]').content;
if (elementContent === ["storm", "storms", "tornado", "snow", "rain", "heat", "cold", "blizzard", "hurricane", "flood", "heat-wave"] > -1); { retrun 'weather' } else if (elementContent === "website"){ return 'article' }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I am very new to this.

Comment: Please share a sample of what `keywords`  value will usually be. If possible, please share a working snippet and expected output.

Comment: That if statement make no sense. 
`if (string === Array that is greater than -1)`

Comment: Why did you tag the question as `json`? There is no [JSON](http://json.org) in it.

Answer (score 1):

> Trying to extract any weather-related keywords from an og:description
>   tag

Given that you have keywords and excludes as

```
var keywords = $('meta[property="og:description"]').attr("content").split(',');
var excludes = ["storm", "storms", "tornado", "snow", "rain", "heat", "cold", "blizzard", "hurricane", "flood", "heat-wave"];
```

`filter` out `excludes` from `keywords` using `includes` (opposite of it) as

```
return keywords.filter( s => !excludes.includes(s.toLowerCase()) )
```

Comment: Here is a view of what their current keywords are. It would be nice to add some value that I can filter the recommendations on like 'weather'

Comment: <meta name="keywords" content="APP > News > Latest News  | 
">

Comment: can you provide an example of how I can test in the console? I am getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement" using the suggestion above, perhaps improperly?

Comment: @Dove On the console you don't need a return keyword since it will return the value by default, or wrap this in a function and invoke that function.